# Firestore: Show all data which are in a city + radius

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

I want to develop an app that shows all restaurants + radius in a city. For example, a user enters Hamburg and selects a radius of 50km. Now all results from the database are displayed, which are in this area.

How do you do this and what approach should you take?

Comment: You are looking for [Geo queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries).

Comment: But how can I include a radius around a city. In the example, only one point is set and a radius is drawn around it. I want to show all results in the city, so I would have to check which locations are in the city limits.

Comment: Then create the radius around the center of the city.

Comment: Thank you! But if I draw a radius of 1km around the center of London, for example, then not all results in London are displayed. In my case I would need all results in London and results that are 1km outside of London.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to develop an app that shows all restaurants + radius in a city.

If you need to allow users to browse restaurants near their current location, then you looking for [Firestore Geo queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries).

> But how can I include a radius around a city. In the example, only one point is set and a radius is drawn around it. I want to show all results in the city, so I would have to check which locations are within the city limits.

In this case, you should create a radius around the center of the city.

> But if I draw a radius of 1km around the center of London, for example, then not all results in London are displayed.

In that case, you should use a different radius value for each city. For example, a small city might need 500m around the city center, while a big metropole should have 2km around the city center.

Alternatively, you can let the user choose the radius and query the database according to it.